# What happens to child table data outside of retention period with partman?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, pg-partman

I am no expert in Partman, so I would like to know what happens to the data in the partitioned child tables when they go outside the retention period?

I know there is the retention_keep_table parameter in part_config, which states that it either drops the child table or keeps it. What happens if I keep it? If I query my table, will I be able to see the data which was in the child table? Is the same the case if it becomes dropped?

I have read through the documentation and have found nothing regarding this.